# time display error in chat application in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am trying to build a chat application. Here, when user types a message and click enter then the text is send on the server and soon a response is received alongwith   comment and a time(in millisecond) i.e. server system time.

When receiving server response for display of comment alongwith time, it is displaying initial time as 6 minutes. However, it should be  'just now'.

I am deciding time with logic as:-

```
// server time is time received in milliseconds as a response from server.

public getTime(servertime): string {
        const seconds = Math.floor(((+new Date()) - servertime) / 1000);

        let interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return interval + 'y';
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return interval + 'M';
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return interval + 'd';
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return interval + 'h';
        }
        interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        if (interval >= 1) {
            return interval + 'm';
        }
            return 'Just now';
    }
```

I am finding a delay of 6 minutes and how to correct it by logic?

Comment: is your server clock and client clock the same time?

Comment: How to check that. Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: log into your server and enter the command ... date ... at the command line (assumes linux) then checking the time on the computer on which you are using the browser is easy